# Multiple generics with Into<PathBuf>

Tags: rust

I'm working on an asset manager for my game engine.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
trait Animal {
    fn create<P>(name: P) -> Self
    where
        P: Into<PathBuf>;
}

struct Dog;

impl Animal for Dog {
    fn create<P>(name: P) -> Self
    where
        P: Into<PathBuf>
    {
        Self {}
    }
}

fn create_animal<A, P>(name: P) -> A
where
    P: Into<PathBuf>,
    A: Animal,
{
    A::create(name)
}
```

When I'm trying to call `create_animal` like this, I'm getting the following error:

```
let dog = create_animal::<Dog>("Spike"); // Error: wrong number of type arguments: expected 2, found 1
```

The only way this function can be called right now is by passing both types explicitly:

```
let dog = create_animal::<Dog, &str>("Spike"); // This code is correct
```

I was wondering if there is any way to use Into with any other trait bound without explicitly passing its type (like in the first example).

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you need the ```create_animal``` factory function? Is there extra stuff going on in there that you've elided out?

Comment: Does `P` need to be a type-parameter? Why not use `&str` as the type for `name`?

Comment: @Dai, in general paths are passed around as `P: AsRef<Path>`. The OP hasn't done this, but has tried something similar with `P: Into<PathBuf>`, however in general adding the type parameter can make it more versatile. Like, if I'm using a `PathBuf` already to build up a path to something and iterating over a directory, I'd definitely not want to deal with creating an `&str` out of that.

Comment: @BrendanWilson, It is actually a method of the `AssetManager` struct. So there is some extra stuff going on inside of it like caching and validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `_` to leave the second type unspecified:

```
let dog = create_animal::<Dog, _>("Spike");
```

Or specify the variable's type:

```
let dog: Dog = create_animal("Spike");
```